# Guide to Grand Canyon wildlife

Tags: nature-and-wildlife, guidebooks, grand-canyon

Are there any guidebooks for finding and identifying wildlife in the Grand Canyon area? For example when (what season, month, time of day, etc.) and where (certain tree types, rocks, near the Visitor Center, etc.) to look for (rabbits, birds, etc.).

Comment: I think people have closed this because it looks like you're asking for a recommendation based on the probability that there are many guidebooks on this topic. If you have done your research and can't find a book then please include details of how you looked and why what you found is not enough, then we should be able to help.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's actually the opposite. I have a strong feeling that no such guide exists. So, I actually haven't spent any time looking for it. I basically want to hire a personal Grand Canyon tour guide who will go with me and point out where and when to look for wildlife without having to actually hire someone. I did start out the post with something like "Can anyone recommend a good book..." not realizing I wasn't supposed to be asking opinion questions. I guess I just thought if someone knew of such a thing off the top of their head it would save me some time. (Too greedy?)

Comment: Basically Stack Exchange isn't a forum. We put in some effort finding answers to questions based on the expectation that answers are not easy to find but others will have similar questions. In return we expect people to also put some effort into their questions. Your comment is good so you should improve your question based on what you've written there and it looks like it will get reopened.

Comment: How do I get this reopened?

Comment: You edit the question to address the reasons it got closed, flesh it out, clarify how/why the reasons it was closed don't apply, generally improve the question. Have a look at the [help section](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help). It will now be listed back with the new questions. Then click on "reopen", which is next to "share" and "edit". If you can't click "reopen" leave a new comment here asking somebody to reopen it after you've improve it.

Comment: I don't see "reopen" next to share and edit. I feel like this is now a good question. Also, I just got back from the Grand Canyon. I found books about the wildlife there in stores there, but none that were really what I was looking for, so if anyone knows the answer to this, I'd still like to know. Thanks!

Comment: I suppose you don't have reopen button because you don't have much "reputation" points. Maybe your other option is to [ask on meta](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) ...

Comment: The age-old how to get reputation points without already having reputation points dilemma. Thanks again!

Comment: There may not be a book specifically on Grand Canyon wildlife, but there certainly are a number on [wildlife in Arizona](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=a9_sc_1?rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Awildlife+guide+arizona&keywords=wildlife+guide+arizona&ie=UTF8&qid=1383397118), which naturally includes the Grand Canyon.

Comment: I guess that would be a fair answer with the potential to be useful for anybody else who might want such a guide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like what you are looking for is a field guide to the Grand Canyon;

> [Field guide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_guide) - a book designed to help the reader identify wildlife
>   (plants or animals) or other objects of natural occurrence (e.g.
>   minerals). It is generally designed to be brought into the 'field' or
>   local area where such objects exist to help distinguish between
>   similar objects

Among others, **[A Field Guide to the Grand Canyon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0898864895)** may be an excellent place to start.